# Modernizr and Video.h264

Tags: javascript, video, h.264, modernizr

I am looking at how Modernizr detects support for [Video and H.264](http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js), but it does not make any sense to me. Isn't `bool` a primitive boolean? why does it become a Boolean object? Why does bool.h264 magically start making any sense at all? thanks

```
tests['video'] = function() {
        var elem = document.createElement('video'),
            bool = false;

        // IE9 Running on Windows Server SKU can cause an exception to be thrown, bug #224
        try {
            if ( bool = !!elem.canPlayType ) {
                bool      = new Boolean(bool);
                bool.ogg  = elem.canPlayType('video/ogg; codecs="theora"')      .replace(/^no$/,'');

                // Without QuickTime, this value will be `undefined`. github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/546
                bool.h264 = elem.canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E"') .replace(/^no$/,'');

                bool.webm = elem.canPlayType('video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"').replace(/^no$/,'');
            }

        } catch(e) { }

        return bool;
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually wrote a majority of that test.

That is just the format that Modernizr has followed for detects with sub values. In JavaScript, everything is an object, and new Boolean is as well.

Comment: Patrick, I am sure it works, but I could use your elaborating on what is going on. And yes, I may not be the biggest expert of javascript on the planet. For example, the function can return bool a primitive type or bool a Boolean wrapper object with sub-properties. In that case, bool.h264 would make no sense. Or are you telling me that people should first check Modernizr.video to be true before they even try Modernizer.video.h264 ?
Confused. Is there such thing as an annotated Modernizr? Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Initially `bool` is indeed a primitive boolean, which cannot have properties added to it. Following the `if` condition, the value of `bool` gets overwritten via `new Boolean(bool)`. In Javascript, calling new on a function, creates an empty Object, and uses the function as a constructor for said object. In the case of the `Boolean()` constructor, the only notable addition to the object, is a `valueOf()` function which returns the original primitive value. Otherwise, you now have a normal Object which can have arbitrary properties added to it.

[See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

Comment: Thanks. I would like to mark both as good answers, but apparently SO won't let me do it.